# Skip offline access permission in Microsoft OIDC authorization

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I'm using this code

```
var app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(AzureAdApplicationId)
   .WithTenantId("organizations")
   .WithRedirectUri(AzureAdRedirectUrl)
   .WithClientSecret(AzureAdSecretKey)
   .Build();

azureAdScopes = new List<string>() { "email" };

var signInRequest = app.GetAuthorizationRequestUrl(azureAdScopes);

var uri = await signInRequest.ExecuteAsync();
```

which produces the url

> https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?scope=email+openid+profile+offline_access&...

All I need is the user's username and I don't need offline access to the user's account. How can I remove them from the scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could request the url without `offline_access`, but Azure AD **v2.0** OAuth2 Account Consent Page automatically lists "Access your data anytime" even though offline_access is not specified in scope. This is an [issue](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/34738855-azure-ad-v2-0-oauth2-account-consent-page-always-l) related.

The **Note** shows in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#requesting-individual-user-consent):

> At this time, the offline_access ("Maintain access to data you have
> given it access to") and user.read ("Sign you in and read your
> profile") permissions are automatically included in the initial
> consent to an application.

Comment: This is too bad. A fix for this, i.e. not including offline_access automatically, was, according to the issue you linked to, promised to be rolled out over 1,5 years ago.

Comment: The note doesn't seem to be available in the doc after the "Entra" rebranding, but it still seems to be automatically included in practice (at least on the consent form). Here is the old doc, just in case: https://web.archive.org/web/20221001055058/https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#requesting-individual-user-consent

Comment: The issue has also moved: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/36f02e36-b625-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0789